# How to properly return HTML when doing AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am fairly new to using AJAX and I do not think I am doing things correctly. the page actually does work fine and as I intended but I do not think I am getting to that result in the proper way. Basically I have a page that loads and will display a table that it gets from the AJAX call. It sends in a couple parameters for pagination purposes so it gets the correct records for the page it is on.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    var offset = document.getElementById('offset').value;
    var sortDirection = "";
    var sortType = "";

    if (document.getElementById('setSortName').value != ""){
        sortType = document.getElementById('setSortName').value;
    }

    if (document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value != ""){
        var sortDirection = document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value;
    }


    $.get("ajaxDistributorManage.php", { offset: offset, sortDirection: sortDirection, sortType: sortType}, 

    function(html) {

        $("#distributorTable").append(html);

        var resort = true;

        $("table").trigger("update", [resort]);

     });    

        return false;
    } 
);
```

AJAX Page

http://pastebin.com/F3gs4QqE

I couldn't get it to properly format easily on directly on stack over flow so I put it on paste bin.

so if anyone can tell me how I should be doing it or point me toward some tutorials on it that'd be awesome. I have looked around online and it seems that AJAX advice differs

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly. Their are many way to do ajax and returning html is a valid option. Can you be more specific as to the problem your running into?

Comment: Can you tell what problem you are facing?

Comment: I actually am not running into any problems. This is something I am working on for work and was told that I did not do it properly so was trying to figure out what I wasn't doing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax and it's shortcut methods $.get, $.post, etc. will do a 'best guess' as to the content type returned.

See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

You can overwrite that best guess if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to return the data in json and build the html in the javascript and then append the html into the dom.
But if you don't want to do that you can just echo html from the php and it will be past into the html variable in the callback function of the AJAX

Comment: do you know of a good example or tutorial that shows how to do that? I know there are lots online but as I said it seems like they differ from each other for how they actually accomplish it.